# list_append causing duplicates in Map. if list_append called for for existing keys in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In following code in java I am trying to append an item "test.com" to a Map field named "daily". When I run this code it just adds a dulplicate key to the Map.

```
Map<String,String> atrVal = new HashMap<String,String>();
                atrVal.put("test.com", json);
                UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                        .withPrimaryKey("id", Id)
                        .withUpdateExpression("set daily = list_append(daily , :r)")
                        .withConditionExpression("attribute_not_exists (daily.#k1)")
                        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                                .withList(":r", Arrays.asList(atrVal))

                                )
                        .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                                .with("#k1", "test.com"));
                table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

`attribute_not_exists` should be preventing it from doing that. Any ideas why its not working.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you would like to append the jsonValues present inside the map daily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have a `MAP` inside the `LIST`, the API expects the index of the list (something like below). In Java terms, the data type of daily is `List<Map<String, String>>`.

When you just say "daily.stringvalue" (i.e. daily."test.com"), it can't find the String value as there is an object (i.e. MAP) present inside the LIST rather than just a STRING value.

```
"attribute_not_exists (daily[0].#k1)"
```

When the index is given, it searches for the key inside the first element.

If the list would have been `List<String>`, there is an option to use `CONTAINS`. However, it can't be used due to the complexity of the model.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so in this case you recommend changing to `"attribute_not_exists (daily[0].#k1)"`? but what if value is not on the first element of that list.

Comment: Currently, API doesn't lookup and work out the index. You need to remodel to flatten the structure. No other workaround. This is the limitation of DynamoDB.